# : yii ajaxSubmitButton won't recognize my action url

Tags: yii

I have an update form, and within that form there is a table where I want to populate using ajax after filling in a couple of fields. I have tried using `ajaxSubmitButton` but somehow it just doesn't trigger the action that I want.

Here is my view:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Insert', array('myController/insertProgress'), array(
         'type' => 'POST',
         'success' => 'function(){
               alert("success");
               }',
         'data' => array(
               'progress' => 'js:$("#progress").val()',
                ),
          )
   );                    
?>
```

myController:

```
public function actionInsertProgress() {
    $data = $_POST['progress'];
    //do stuff here, including echoing the table row
}
```

When I click the submit button, it doesn't trigger the `insertProgress` action, but instead the main form action which is `actionEdit`. It's as if the URL that I provided is being ignored.

The url for this form goes something like this:
`(sitename)/(modulename)/myController/edit/id/57`

Thank you.

EDIT: I do have another submit button to update the whole form, which triggers the `actionEdit` action.

EDIT2: this is what the widget produces:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery(function($) {
jQuery('body').on('click','#yt0',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','data':{'progress':$("#progress").val()},'url':'http://inarac.id/adm/topikkajian/insertProgress','cache':false});return false;});
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using module you should add the modele path to your link

```
  $myLink = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) . 
         '/index.php/moduleName/myController/insertProgress';

<?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Insert',   
       $myLink, array(
     'type' => 'POST',
     'success' => 'js:function(){
           alert("success");
           }',
     'data' => array(
           'progress' => 'js:$("#progress").val()',
            ),
      )
   );                    
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried adding the module path as you mentioned, but still it ignored the url that I provided and triggered `actionEdit` instead of `actionInsertProgress`. (`$myLink = Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) .'/adm/topikkajian/insertProgress';` )

Comment: Or try simply digit  the path / url  in the browser in this  way you test if the url is right

Comment: I checked, and it did point to the correct location, but `ajaxSubmitButton` just wouldn't work with it. Yes, I have tested the url `$myLink` produces and it turns out fine. I really don't know where I've gone wrong here...

Comment: For test you should use js:function for alert- I have update the answer